# How to add headers to odata get service

Tags: odata, sapui5, sap-gateway

I am working on following odata service:

https://10.49.78.69:8083/gateway/odata/SAP/SOA_LOGIN_GET_DATA;v=1/InspectionSet

This service runs only when following four headers are defined.

```
InterfaceID ADFCA_CRM_SBL_023
LanguageType    ENU / ARA
UserName    SHEENAR
Password    Sheenar#123
```

I have tried using filters as follows but no success.

[https://10.49.78.69:8083/gateway/odata/SAP/SOA_LOGIN_GET_DATA;v=1/InspectionSet?$filter=UserName eq 'SHEENAR' and Password eq 'Sheenar#123' and InterfaceID eq 'ADFCA_CRM_SBL_023' and LanguageType eq 'ENU'

Guess headers have to be declared specifically.

Kindly suggest how these headers can be written while setting data to model in SAP UI5.

Comment: What error message do you get when you try to use the filters in the url?

Comment: Can you add the parts of the code where you bind the model and where you try to call the data?

Answer (score 3):

after creating the instance `oDataModel`,

```
var oDataModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(sServiceUrl, mParameters);
oDataModel.setHeaders(mHeaders)
```

Parameters:

```
{object} mHeaders :the header name/value map.
```

Read more [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#setHeaders)